# How to Give Lexical and Grammatical Meanings

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, lexicon

I am genuinely confused by one of the items on our Learning Task. It says we have to **PICK 5 PHRASES FROM A SONG AND GIVE THEIR LEXICAL ANG GRAMMATICAL MEANING**

I think I understand lexical and grammatical meaning. But I thought they're just abstract concepts we have to understand, not like "denotation" for example, where I can give the definition of words. So I honestly don't know how to go about answering this particular item. Or maybe I'm just stupid. English is not my first language so I acknowledge I might have poor comprehension.

Here's what I tried from what I understood:

*You don't own me*

**Lexical Meaning:**

referring expression: You

predicate: don't own me

**Grammatical Meaning:** ???

Comment: If it means 'give the definitions, nuances and etymologies of every word. and explain the grammar involved', you'll be here till Christmas 2021. I'd take this as a badly worded 'explain what they mean'.

Comment: @Cascabel example: "Fly me to the moon"

Comment: ok sorry @Cascabel i just read your comment

Comment: ok thank u for you time cascabel. have a nice day.

Comment: Why don't you ask the instructor who imposed this task on you? Not only would that give you the answer that is much more relevant for your purposes than anything anybody here might say, but it would, one hopes, also make the instructor aware that the instructions are badly worded.

Comment: My guess is that it wants you to give the literal meaning as well as the figurative meaning.  But that’s just a guess.

Comment: The question is confusing, but these definitions from MW somewhat clarify it: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexical%20meaning, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammatical%20meaning

Comment: How about explaining the plainest meaning of the phrase, and then what it conveys? So, you cannot be my owner...and you cannot boss me around like property.

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster:

[lexical meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexical%20meaning)

> the meaning of the base (such as the word play) in a paradigm (such as
> plays, played, playing)

[grammatical meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammatical%20meaning)

> the part of meaning that varies from one inflectional form to
> another (as from plays to played to playing)

But, I'll note, many songs don't use that many different "inflectional forms", and so would make poor examples.